# Is there a way to make my tablet turn off when not charging?

Tags: applications, root-access, developer-options

I am planning to mount my android tablet to my car with a charging cable permanantly left in. The idea is as soon as I turn the car on, the tablet starts charging,  and as soon as I turn the car off, the charging stops. (I'm prepared to accept the reduced battery life as a result).

It would be ideal to have the tablet turn on automatically as soon as the car does, and turn off automatically once the car does. I have found a way online to have the tablet turn on as soon as it starts charging, but I cannot find a way to make the Tablet/Android turn off once the charging stops. Could you please advise if there is an app, or a file that can be added/changed to make this happen?

Comment: Llama, an automation tool like Tasker (so probably Tasker, too), can detect the changing states of power, either input or draw. With this as a condition, you could make the device sleep/wake as desired.

Comment: Tasker will do that after a bit of setting up.. It takes a bit to get it working exactly how you need.

Answer (score 1):

### For rooted devices:

To have your device power off as soon as it stops charging, You can use an app called [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid).

1. On the main page of the app, press on *add macro*  → *battery/power  → power connected/disconnected  → power disconnected*
2. press on *actions* (found, on the top)  → *device actions  → reboot/power off  → power off  → ok.*
3. press on the ✓ on the bottom right of the screen, and give a name to this action.

Now, when your phone is charging, and you unplug it, or in this case, turn off your car, it will automatically power off.

### Non-rooted devices:

As far as I know, you cannot automate this action on non-rooted devices.

Therefore, the best suggestion I can give, is to have the power off dialog show up as soon as you turn off your car. That way, all you have to do is just press on *power off*.

1. Download [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid).
2. On the main page of the app, press on *add macro*  → *battery/power  → power connected/disconnected  → power disconnected*
3. press on *actions* (found, on the top)  → *device actions  → Android shortcuts  → power options  → ok*
4. press on the ✓ on the bottom right of the screen, and give a name to this action.

Now when you turn your car off, the power off dialog will popup and you can press on *power off*